# Downsides of converting crypto.randomInt() into a float?

Tags: node.js, math, random

I think this could be a rather silly question, but it might not. I'm wondering what would the downsides of getting a securely generated integer and turning it into a float, aside from some considerations for the precision. This is an example function:

```
randomFloat: function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    crypto.randomInt(1, 100001, function (error, result) {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(result / 100000);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

This would turn `1` into `0.00001` which in my case is more than enough.

Edit: I'm using this as `rng` for `rarities` in a game I'm working on. So if below 0.7 a specific rarity is assigned and so on.

Comment: It shouldn't matter as you're just shifting the decimal point... Depending on the actual use case, other implications might arise though. P.S. welcome to StackOverflow :D

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as "just shifting the decimal point", though. The fact that we're switching from int to IEEE floating point means we have to completely change bit representation, and something like 1 / 10 does _not_ "just shift the decimal point" to become 0.1: IEEE floats by definition _can't_ represent 0.1, so it really depends on what you need these numbers for. The best answer to "are there downsides?" in absence of the actual use case is "maybe?", rather than "this should be fine".

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - But nodejs does not have regular `int` data types, it only has `Number` or `BigInt`.  But, if you look at the doc for `crypto.randomInt()`, you can see that it is using the double floating point Number for both input and output so its is result is already represented as a double floating point number.  So, dividing by 100000 is indeed, just changing the exponent on the double.

Comment: Without saying *why* you're converting the random integer to a double we can't analyze for downsides. The software is happy to do it and the result won't break the computer.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks, I've updated the question with my use case.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the question specifically states aside from precision considerations

Comment: Without a use-case, there is no way to know whether someone understands why they'd state that. "precision" alone is not a thing, but the consequences of precision _as it relates to the use-case_ is, so that's the thing we really need to know before we can tell whether that statement made sense.

Comment: @jfriend00 I didn't say we were converting data types, we're switching number types, which matters as the integer use of Number is perfectly well behaved up to 2^53-1, but the float use of Number has all the quirks of IEEE floating point decimal values.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - There is no "switching number types" in Javascript.  They are all stored as doubles, whether they are integer values or whether they have decimal parts.

Comment: Now you're just ignoring the meaning of words: we use Number, but we use Number in different ways for integer numbers vs. decimal fractionals. By switching the kind of number we need mathematically (we as in we the programmer), we cross over from "Number using only the bits that yield safe integers" to "Number using all the bits that give us all the IEEE floating point quirks". _We_ switch number types, and that switch has repercussions. The JS engine doesn't switch internal data types, but it _does_ change which bits its now using within that same, double-backed, data type.